# Why is $ \mathbb{E} \limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_n = \mathbb{E} \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} X_n$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

For a sequence of positive random variables $X_n$ (which i assumed is not nessesarily monotonically non decreasing). Assuming that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} X_n = X$

I don't understand why $ \mathbb{E} \limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_n = \mathbb{E} \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} X_n$.

Because according to my understanding, $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}X_n(\omega)$ for disjoint $\omega$ is not necessarily increasing, hence for disjoint set of $\omega$ $A$ and $B$, it could be either $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} X_n (\omega_A)= X(\omega_A)$ or $\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} X_n (\omega_B)= X(\omega_B)$

Comment: This has nothing to do with probability; it's just a property of real numbers (or extended reals $[-\infty,\infty]$). The limit $\lim$ of a sequence in $[-\infty,\infty]$ exists if and only if $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ (which always exist) are equal. In this case, $\liminf=\limsup=\lim$. In your hypothesis, $\lim X_n=X$ indicates the limit exists, so $\limsup X_n=\lim X_n=X$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo that makes alot of sense, thanks